# What's the difference between setTransformMatrix and setProjectionMatrix in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx, mathematics, matrix

There are two method of [`SpriteBatch`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html) in LibGDX: `setTransformMatrxi` and `setProjectionMatrix`.

I know one can use `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)` to define how/where an object should be rendered on the screen. But then what does `setTransformMatrix` do?

I googled "difference between transform matrix and projection matrix" but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformation matrix:

This matrix defines **where** to render your geometry.

Projection matrix:

Don't use this matrix to move stuff around, it's not meant to. This matrix defines **how** to render your geometry. For example, this can make the game render in a perspective projection (things farther away are smaller) or in an ortographic projection (everything is the same size). This is where `camera.combined` should go.

They aren't interchangeable, because they get multiplied in the shaders, and matrix multiplication is not cummulative.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still a little battled. For example when I move my camera, doesn't it change *where* to render my geometry? Should this change be implemented via transformation matrix or projection matrix?

Comment: @LaiYu-Hsuan ask the questions highlighted in my question. Does moving the camera change how the objects are rendered or where? Obviously the latter one. Moving a camera basically just moves everything else in the other direction.